# Reset $scope rather than refresh page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When the page loads the $scope is fresh and clean. I would like to store that fresh state and when the user clicks a reset button it would reset the $scope back to as it was when the page loaded. The code below doesn't work but is along the lines of what I would like to happen. How can I store the original $scope and then reset it after the $scope has been changed?

```
(function () {
    //function that fires when button is clicked
    $scope.resetScope = function () {
        $scope = freshScope;
    }

    //$scope is stored on page load
    freshScope = $scope;
});
```

Comment: are you trying to reset the values of form elements?

Comment: `The code below doesn't work` Meaning nothing happens or you get an error or your computer blows up or...?

Comment: if your aim is to reset a series of form elements, there is an angular function for that `$scope.formName.$setPristine()`.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine.

Comment: By doesn't work I mean that the freshScope variable stays current with the $scope.  If I change the $scope then for some reason the variable changes as well.

Comment: @AndrewCounts I am not trying to reset form elements.

Comment: `$scope` itself is an internal Angular class that does a lot more than just store your variables as it's properties.  You can reset all of the objects you are having `$scope` track, but trying to erase the `$scope` object all together and create a fresh one would really require hacking into the internals of Angular.  What is it you are trying to do that you think this is necessary?

Comment: `$scope` is an object. When you do `freshScope = $scope` you haven't created a copy of the object - you have created a new reference to the same object. And, btw, `$scope` is not meant to be copied (e.g. with `angular.copy`). Instead, clone the objects (i.e. your ViewModel) that you attach to a scope.

Comment: I decided to put all $scope variables in $scope.scope so that I could angular.copy it. Not as clean as I'd like it to be but it works.